# What is the function return type that can handle type null?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement conditional rendering in typescript and currently when `null` is used as alternative I get following error message

"Type 'Element | null' is not assignable to type 'Element'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any>'"

So if I delete `JSX.Element` then typescript complains missing type on return function. Other alternative is to replace `null` with `(<></>)`. This works but I read somewhere this takes extra space in dom so null is better solution. So is there function return type that can handle null or any alternative approach to this?

```
export const ContextPanel = ({
  children,
}: React.PropsWithChildren<LayoutContextInterface>): JSX.Element => {
  const context = React.useContext(LayoutContext);
  return context.contextPanelOpen ? (
    <div className={styles.contextPanelWidth}>{children}</div>
  ) : null;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [FunctionComponent](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L549) type instead (check it out for details on what the proper return type is if you want to manually type it yourself.

```
export const ContextPanel: React.FunctionComponent = ({
  children
}) => {
  const context = React.useContext(LayoutContext);
  return context.contextPanelOpen ? (
    <div className={styles.contextPanelWidth}>{children}</div>
  ) : null;
};
```

For reference, here is the definitition of the `FunctionComponent` interface at the time of writing this answer. See the link for an up-to-date version.

```
 interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
        (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
        propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P> | undefined;
        contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any> | undefined;
        defaultProps?: Partial<P> | undefined;
        displayName?: string | undefined;
    }
```

Note the return type here is `ReactElement<any, any> | null`. I suspect your original answer would've worked if you simply typed your return properly with `JSX.Element | null`, but overall this typing is probably more accurate.

Comment: If I use `React.FunctionComponent` then I have to declare children prop in interface separately as oppose to using `React.PropsWithChildren`, there is no need to declare children prop in interface. There is always trade off I guess. Thank you for detailed response!

Comment: I'm unclear on what other props you're using besides `chidlren` here? If you want to declare extra props types, just pass them into `FunctionComponent<{ someProp: type} >` like so